# Tell Twilio when it is acceptable to break sms message

Tags: php, sms, twilio

I am sending a fairly long SMS message through Twilio's API, around 200 characters or so.

Is it possible to tell Twilio when it is acceptable to send another message?

For instance, I am sending this message.

```
Customer: Last Name, First Name
Job Title: Weekly Lawncare
Job Description: Cut grass, edge.
Start Date: 24 Sept 2014
Finish Date: 25 Sept 2014
Status: In Progress
```

It is acceptable for Twilio to break it after the line has finished, but not in the middle of a phone number, ID, or email.

This is the PHP used to send the message.

```
$message = "Customer: " . $job_data->last_name . ", " . $job_data->first_name . "\n";
$message .= "Job Title: " . $job_data->title . "\n";
$message .= "Job Description: " . $job_data->description . "\n";
$message .= "Start Date: " . $job_data->start_date . "\n";
$message .= "Finish Date: " . $job_data->finish_date . "\n";
$message .= "Status: " . $job_data->status . "\n";

$client->account->messages->sendMessage($me, $sender, $message);
```

I haven't been able to find any sort of documentation concerning this, so I am afraid it needs to be done manually.

Answer (score 4):

No, its not possible to tell Twilio to break after any line finished.
You need to it manually.

For outgoing messages, concatenated messages are there with TWILIO when sending messages to phone numbers in US and Canada. With the Messages resource URI, you can send messages containing up to 1600 characters. When TWILIO receive your request, Twilio will auto segment messages with more than 160 characters and the messages will be automatically reassembled on the destination handset.

Refer:https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-do-i-add-a-line-break-in-my-sms-message
https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/does-twilio-support-concatenated-sms-messages-or-messages-over-160-characters

After seeing this, I Think you will get your answer.

Comment: Note: the message resource URI is depreciated.